# constexpr class and template function match

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constexpr

I am trying out constexpr to get a feel for functionality and I see it can make template metaprogramming a bit more easier (If I am understanding it correctly).

I have this dummy example where a class has a const number field, and ctor being marked constexpr should behave like a compile time constant. Which it does but some how fails with template function matching:

```
#include <iostream>

class ConstNum
{
public:
    constexpr ConstNum(int num) : _num(num)
    {
    }

    constexpr int number() const
    {
        return _num;
    }

private:
    const int _num;
};


template<class T, size_t N>
constexpr int num_elements(const T (&arr) [N])
{
    return N;
}

int main()
{
    ConstNum c1(3);
    char arr[c1.number()];

    //  fails to compile here with error message:
    //  No matching function for call to num_elements
    //  
    std::cout << num_elements(arr) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I am running on XCode, the error message gives details about this being
semantic issue: additional text being:

1. Candidate template ignored: could not match 'const T[N]' against
   'char [c1.number()]

If I replace c1.number() by 3 this compiles fine.
Or If i remove the std::cout call entirely this compiles fine.

Any ideas what am I missing here.
Thank you

Sarang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if function marked as `constexpr` it *may* evaluate at run-time. If you want compile-time evaluation, you should add `constexpr` specifier to `c1` object, otherwise it will be constructed at run-time:

```
constexpr ConstNum c1(3);
```

Output:

```
> ./main
3
```

Tip: Clang with enabled warnings gives the following output for your code:

```
main.cpp:29:13: warning: variable length arrays are a C99 feature [-Wvla-extension]
    char arr[c1.number()];
```

This means, that `c1.number()` was not evaluated at compile time, as you expected